How to get non-zero exit code from git diff --no-index only on errors?
I'm using git diff --no-index to compare two directories outside a GIT repository because git diff handles renames efficiently as opposed to GNU diff.
The man page says that --no-index implies --exit-code, and --exit-code means "return non-zero exit code if there are differences, zero if no differences".
I want to stop after a git diff error (for example if it cannot read files). Is there a way to distinguish errors from differences in the compared directories ?

Since git diff is porcelain I'd expect it to output something to stderr if anything fails, so maybe try that as the deciding factor.

It does seem to return exitcode 128 if I give it an unknown cmdline argument, and exitcode 1 if there are changed files.

Return exitcode 129 for me if I give it an unknown cmdline argument. Exitcode 1 if there are non-existing files. GNU diff returns 2 in both cases, 1 if the files are different, 0 if the files are identical.

Then hopefully 0 means identical, 1 means different files, and anything else is an error.

No, for git diff 1 means both different and error (non-readable files). Only GNU diff distinguish different files and an error.
